# filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed

Tags: php, fopen, filesize

I am getting the following error when trying to echo the HTML contents of a file inside a wordpress plugin folder.

> Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for 
>   http://bestideabox.com/wp-content/plugins/jww-namechord/
>   includes/template-files/single-form.html in 
>   /home/bestidea/public_html/wp-content/plugins/
>   jww-namechord/includes/core.php on line 44

Here is the function that reads the file:

```
return jww_display_file( 
        plugins_url( 'template-files/'.$template.'.html',__FILE__ ) 
    );


        function jww_display_file( $fileToRead ){

            //Open the file and read it
            $handle = fopen( $fileToRead, "r" );
            $contents = fread( $handle, filesize( $fileToRead ) );
            fclose( $handle );

            //return it
            return $contents;
        }
```

I am at a complete loss. Any Help would be appreciated.

---

Not sure how to mark this as an answer, but thanks to DaveRandom I have a solution:

> The http:// wrapper does not support stat(). You cannot filesize() a
>   HTTP URL. You can use the Content-Length: header of the response if
>   the server returns one, but you actually don't need to here. Just
>   replace the entire body of that function with return
>   file_get_contents($fileToRead); and you're set. – DaveRandom

To those who marked as duplicate. You can see from answer it is not the same issue. Thanks guys for all your help!

Comment: This is what is inside the HTML file - <p align="center">Baby Naming 101 - <i>No &quot;Y&quot; support</i></p>
  <table width="50%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Enter Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="NameText" onChange="convertName()" />
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter ID:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="namecord"5 />
      <input type="submit" name="submit-form-button" id="submit-form-button" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

Comment: What's the value of `fileToRead`? If it's a URL, not a regular filename, `filesize()` doesn't work.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: And it doesn't matter what's in the HTML file.

Comment: The [`http://`](http://php.net/wrappers.http) wrapper does not support `stat()`. You cannot `filesize()` a HTTP URL. You can use the `Content-Length:` header of the response if the server returns one, but you actually don't need to here. Just replace the entire body of that function with [`return file_get_contents($fileToRead);`](http://php.net/file-get-contents) and you're set.

Comment: @Dave.. make this an answer

Comment: Dave. You are the man! that worked great!!!