# PHP function stat(): stat failed for remote image

Tags: php, filesize, stat

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114794/filesize-function-filesize-stat-failed) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226685/warning-filectime-stat-failed-for-path) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48360847/warning-filesize-stat-failed-for-error) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386082/filemtime-warning-stat-failed-for), but all involve performing stat() or filesize() on local files, which don't work because you need the full path.

This problem is different, since I have a handful of remote images that have the full paths and I am still unable to retrieve the size of them. Here is an example:

```
stat("https://cdn-img.health.com/sites/default/files/1532113674/1-opener-sleep-a-z-GettyImages-485559412.jpg");
```

This throws an error saying "stat failed". I'm also unable to get the image size from the filesize() function, retrieving the "Content-Length" or "X-Original-Content-Length" headers (which aren't passed), or curling the image and retrieving the CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD field. Similarly, in Ruby, I am unable to get the size of this image with the traditional methods with the exception of the [Mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) library, which just works. Here are the headers to the image in the example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:   image/jpeg
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  max-age=1800
Date:   Fri, 03 Aug 2018 14:08:39 GMT
ETag:   "90c755-5717304f98380-gzip"
Expires:    Fri, 03 Aug 2018 14:38:39 GMT
Last-Modified:  Fri, 20 Jul 2018 19:08:22 GMT
P3P:    CP='PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA PRE CUR ADMa DEVa TAIo PSAo PSDo IVAo IVDo CONo TELo OTPi OUR UNRo PUBi OTRo IND DSP CAO COR'
Server: Apache
TI-Varnish-Age: 0
Via:    1.1 varnish, 1.1 ba150248cd293ea895c35304503c9f27.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Varnish:  1920400558
Vary:   Accept-Encoding
Age:    19
X-Cache:    Hit from cloudfront
X-Amz-Cf-Id:    pKXUfsB5egUfk4Te7oxIG7TgFLoUfMSUWqGZxd5822_ejvorITbFsg==
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size by doing:

```
strlen(file_get_contents('http://link.of/image.jpg'));
```

As long as you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled it will work. Otherwise you will need to use cURL.

Answer (score 2):

In order for stat() to determine the file size for a remote file the underlying wrapper needs to support stat, from the [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php):

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with *some* URL wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

If you look up the [HTTP wrapper](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) in the documentation:

> Supports stat()    - No

Most functions that take files as an argument rely on wrappers to perform remote operations, so none of these functions will be able to get the remote file size. The [cURL functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) are probably your best bet if that extension is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to get file info, lets say if you want to get size of any file at any url then use this function:

```
            function getFileSizeByCurl($url) {  
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
            }


                            //Calling a function 
            echo getFileSizeByCurl('https://cdn-img.health.com/sites/default/files/1532113674/1-opener-sleep-a-z-GettyImages-485559412.jpg');
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Also, you probably want to close out the curl before ending the function